# In wordpress How to add gallery block programmatically with PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created migration script in PHP. I am migrating data from old WordPress to new latest WordPress version 6. In my old WordPress there is a separate third party gallery plugin. I would like to migrate that gallery media in Guttenberg gallery block. By php script I have downloaded all the images. But now How can I create gallery block with PHP and how to insert multiple images in that gallery block? I know the pattern of image gallery which is like below. But I am not getting exact steps for image regeneration, adding images in post/post meta table then creating gallery block and map all images with gallery block and finally map the gallery with main post.

```
<!-- wp:gallery {"linkTo":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-gallery has-nested-images columns-default is-cropped"><!-- wp:image {"id":166,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="https://www.testlocal.org/user/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2023/02/Aga-Khan-Palace-Pune-India-1024x666.webp" alt="" class="wp-image-166"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":168,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="https://www.testlocal.org/user/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2023/02/Aryabhata-I-statue-Inter-University-Centre-for.webp" alt="" class="wp-image-168"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
<!-- /wp:gallery -->
```

If anyone has done this kind of job then please let me know. It would be great help!!!

In short with php script I would like to add gallery block in my existing post and in that gallery I would like to add multiple images and videos (everthing should be php programmatically)